# Differentiating server-side if Refresh or Search Reset was clicked in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to know that the request was due to the refresh button being clicked or the search's reset button being clicked. I would like to be able to do a getvar server-side and see something like `searchreset=true` or `refresh=true`. I know it will involve manipulating postData. It probably involves listening for click events and overriding them. Any ideas of how to do this?

I've came across `onReset` but somebody said that is triggered after the request is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want, but the implementation can be about the following:

```js
var $grid = $('#grid');

$('#grid').jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (typeof this.p.postData.searchreset !== "undefined") {
            delete this.p.postData.searchreset;
        }
    }
});

$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {refreshstate: 'current', edit: false, add: false, del: false,
        beforeRefresh: function () {
            $grid[0].p.postData.refresh = true;
        },
        afterRefresh: function () {
            delete $grid[0].p.postData.refresh;
        }
    },
    {}, {}, {}, {onReset: function () {
        $grid[0].p.postData.searchreset = true;
    }});
```